# Continuous Integration error in build path in build project tfs visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, continuous-integration

I am trying to create a `Continuous Integration - CI`. I am using `build.proj` to build the project during the `CI` after the build runs the following error appeared

```
C:\Builds\3\ADSVC\HCMS - Continues Integration\src\build.proj (22): The command ""C:\Builds\3\ADSVC\HCMS - Continues Integration\src\.nuget\NuGet.exe" restore "C:\Builds\3\ADSVC\HCMS - Continues Integration\src\HCMS.sln"" exited with code 1
```

The issue in `C:\Builds\3\ADSVC\HCMS - Continues Integration\src\build.proj` but folder `3` is not included in Builds folder I have only one folder called `1` when by chance the pass is `C:\Builds\1\ADSVC\HCMS - Continues Integration\src\build.proj` the build success

also I am having the following properties `Working Directory` in `TFS Build Agent` `$(SystemDrive)\Builds\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionPath)`

**Hint**  I changed the `$(BuildAgentId)` to `$(BuildAgentName)` and its not working too there is no folder

My **Build.proj** is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Project ToolsVersion="4.0"
     DefaultTargets="Build"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

   <PropertyGroup>
        <ProjectPath>$(SystemDrive)\Builds1\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionPath)
   </ProjectPath>
   <OutDir Condition=" '$(OutDir)'=='' ">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)bin\      
   </OutDir>
   <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='' ">Release</Configuration>
   <SourceHome Condition=" '$(SourceHome)'=='' ">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)src\</SourceHome>
   <ToolsHome Condition=" '$(ToolsHome)'=='' ">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory).nuget\</ToolsHome>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <Solution Include="$(SourceHome)*.sln">
     <AdditionalProperties>OutDir=$(OutDir);Configuration=$(Configuration)</AdditionalProperties>
  </Solution>
 </ItemGroup>

 <Target Name="RestorePackages">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(ToolsHome)NuGet.exe&quot; restore &quot;$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)HCMS.sln&quot;" />
 </Target>

  <Target Name="Clean">
    <MSBuild Targets="Clean"
         Projects="@(Solution)" />
   </Target>

  <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="RestorePackages">
    <MSBuild Targets="Build"
         Projects="@(Solution)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Rebuild" DependsOnTargets="RestorePackages">
     <MSBuild Targets="Rebuild"
         Projects="@(Solution)" />
   </Target>


 </Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no parameter of $(BuildAgentName). Every time you created a build agent of build control. TFS will automatically create a folder named as the AgentID under builds on the machine which host the agent. If you delete the agent and readd it. The AgentID will also be a new one.

There must be a agent which has the agentID 3. Not in your local machine, should on some other computer. Not sure why your CI build will copy your solution to the agent working folder C:\Builds\3 .

Try this workaround: delete your C:\Builds on your agent machine and rebuild it. It will recreate a new one check whether got the same error.

---

**Update**

Usually we don't need to change Build.proj, **most customization can be achieved through build process**.  Unless this is used in TFS2005 or TFS2008.

First, try to create a new porject and build it to **check whether your Build.proj caused this error**.

If you have changed `$(SystemDrive)\Builds1\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionPath)` in the working directory of the agent properties, now all other builds using this agent will change to C:\Builds1\1\xxx

If you didn't change the value, since you have messed up the working directory folder, you can **delete the C:\builds** on your agent machine(server), it will automatically recreate a new one when you trigger a new build of the agent.

Comment: There is no Folder in my Machine the CI builds on tfs server directly so the files is in the server not in my machine
I tried to change the name of folder in agent to be `$(SystemDrive)\Builds1\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionPath)` instead of `$(SystemDrive)\Builds\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionPath)` and the same error happened only one time add files to the new path and the build is succeeded in this case. then run many times with the other folder which i don't know where it is and the build is failed

Comment: Sorry, I didn't express well. I just mean the folder in the server(your agent machine). Have you fixed your issue?    Usually we don't need to change Build.proj, most customization can be achieved through build process. Try to create a new porject and build it  to check whether your Build.proj  caused this error. And how did you change $(SystemDrive)\Builds1\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionPath) , did you change it in the Build.proj or in the working directory of the agent properties. Have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you i found the issue there was another agent created and assigned to the controller in another server once i found these agents and disable them the issue is fixed now